# How to export and import the schema of an HBase table?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I am playing with HBase export command:

```
 hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export "t1" t1
```

By inspecting the contents of files inside `t1/` , I can only presume that the schema is not exported together. Indeed,

```
 echo "disable 't1' ; drop 't1'"  | hbase shell
 hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import "t1" t1
```

will fail recovering `t1`. The table has to be previously created, and with the proper schema, so the data can be reloaded. So: how to export the schema of the table `t1`, and how to import it back?

Note that, in this question, the "import" step is very important. It is very clear that I can export that information with:

```
echo "describe 't1'"  | hbase shell
```

However, the output looks pretty impractical to be automatically used to reproduce the table.